# insertion in array of pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Please fix this program.

```
int *arr[2]={10,20};

arr[1]=arr;

*arr[1]=30;

printf("%d",arr);
```

I cannot insert 30 into arr[0],arr[1] is point to &arr and then i insert 30 to arr[0].

Comment: C does not let you invent your own semantic. Specifically, `arr[1]=arr;` does not mean "extend `arr` by one element". In fact, C has no operations with this semantic at all.

Comment: This looks pretty random. `int *arr[2]` defines an array of 2 *pointers* to integer. But it's initialized to `10` and `20` which are not valid pointers. And the request, *Please fix this program* assumes that the audience knows what on earth the program is *supposed* to do (versus what it *does* do), which is quite unclear at this point.

Comment: You can't extend an array that is declared in that way: you can only extend an array that was allocated dynamically, with `malloc()` or `calloc()`, by using `realloc()`.

Comment: "C does not let you invent your own semantic"  But I want to! `#define int int*`

Answer (score 2):

You have a severe error here

```
int *arr[2]={10,20};
```

you are not declaring an array of integrs, it's an array of `int` pointers, and initializing it that way is incorrect.

The right thing to do is to remove the `*`, so it would look like

```
int arr[2] = {10, 20};
```

you cannot simply append to it with

```
arr[2] = 30;
```

because space for only two elements has been allocated and hence you are not authorized to access whatever is at `arr[2]`, so you cannot assign to it, if you know in advance the length of the array then you could do this

```
int arr[KNOWN_LENGTH_WHICH_IS_GREATER_THAN_TWO] = {10, 20};
```

then

```
arr[2] = 30;
```

will store `30` in the 3rd position in the array, if you don't know the size in advance, then you need to use `malloc()`, first you declare a poitner to `int`

```
int *arr;
```

now you make it point to valid memory like this

```
arr = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

above you just requested enough space to store `2` `int`'s and point to it with the `arr` pointer, now you must check that the pointer is indeed pointing to valid memory, in the event there was a problem and `malloc()` was not able to give you the address to valid memory it returns a special value `NULL`, so you check that

```
if (arr == NULL)
    pleaseAbortUsing_arr_ItsInvalid();
```

in the code above you need to handle this the best you can, you could cleanup other resources and return `NULL` if you are in a function, sometimes it's even necessary to terminate the program, but it depends.

Now that your pointer is pointing to valid memory you can store values to that memory, the usual array subscript notation works perfectly so just

```
arr[0] = 10;
arr[1] = 20;
```

but again you can't add a third number because there is not enough space, in this case however you can use `realloc()`, this function will increase the size of the pointed to block or point to a new one and copy the contents of the old one if necessary, so to use it you do this

```
void *pointer;

pointer = realloc(arr, 3 * sizeof(int));
if (pointer == NULL)
 {
     free(arr);
     pleaseAbortUsing_arr_ItsInvalid();
 }
arr    = poitner; 
arr[2] = 30;
```

again handle the error the best you can, finally when you are done using `arr` you call `free()` on it like this

```
free(arr);
```

if `arr` is going to be returned from a function you call `free` when the caller has finished using it, in fact you call free whenever you want and meanwhile the data will be valid, for the whole lifetime of the program if you need it.

Answer (score -1):

```
int arr[3] = {10,20, 0};

arr[2] = 30;

printf("%d, %d, %d\n",arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
```

You should probably look up C syntax because nothing you've done so far makes any sense.